# How avoid duplicate data entry via php to mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

We have a table vehicle and a simple php form. Before inserting data I do check if the vehicle registration number exist but some client pc could enter duplicate entries. Below is the code snippet. What else could be causing this ?

```
$vehicleRegistrationNumber=$_POST['vehicleRegistrationNumber'];
$selectQuery1 ="Select vehicleRegistrationNumber From Vehicle Where vehicleRegistrationNumber='".$vehicleRegistrationNumber."'"; 
$result1 = mysqli_query($link,$selectQuery1);
$row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$n1 = mysqli_num_rows($result1);

if($n1 > 0) {
  $status="<span class=\"statusFailed\">: Vehicle ".$vehicleRegistrationNumber." Already Exist.</span>";
}
else {
  //insert codes
}
```

Comment: Why don´t just use UNIQUE index on vehicleRegistrationNumber? That way mysql will handle it for you and you just have to take care about the error you will get if you try to insert duplicate row.

Comment: Yes I have now done that on the UNIQUE INDEXING but what could be the problem via the browser that this check failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. This check can be bypassed by submitting something like `XYZ0001' AND 1='0` or even more malicious values. To prevent this, use prepared statements and param binding instead of string concatenation.

Other possibility is simply user mistake, for example trailing space (`"XYZ001" != "XYZ0001 "`) that is hard to spot on the first glance ad records in DB. Before checking its existence in DB you should check with PHP if submitted value includes only allowed chars and is free from common mistakes.

Comment: so I got few other codes where I do this sort of check. So how to avoid them or strengthen on their security? So how avoid the common mistakes in php and over come on the sql injection will this be a help fullful if I put them in mysql_real_escape_string() ?

Comment: You are using `mysqli` in your code, so if you insist on not using prepared statement, use `mysqli_real_escape_string`. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/258674) you can read more about sql injections. As for common mistakes you have to define patterns for desired data and check if it fits your requirements, and if not, prompt the user with desired format.

Comment: I have been using mysqli_real_escape_string it in my other pages. IS it safe enough or should I move to prepaered statements?

Answer (score 1):

try this with group by

```
 $selectQuery1 ="Select vehicleRegistrationNumber From Vehicle Where vehicleRegistrationNumber='".$vehicleRegistrationNumber."' GROUP BY vehicleRegistrationNumber";
```

Comment: the funny part it that without the group by also should be able to check right?

Comment: what you mean by use php? I am running it on php ? So what else could be failing it something strange rite.

Comment: i mean you can also filter duplicates by php i know you are using php :)

Comment: How to filter duplicates by php I thought by looking via the select statement should be helpful but I notice it is working fine on my side but when my clients do it by pass that check. That is the strange part .

Comment: i gave you my answer to dont get duplicates  it doesnt help ?

Comment: I will try that too but what I dont understand is that what is the wrong with my existing query can you point out on that ?

Comment: your query , you forgot GROUP BY statment

Comment: @echo_Samir can you explain why adding `GROUP BY` should help?

Comment: YEs how will the group by be a help and why the basic query will fail any reason please?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to handle it on the SQL side. Just define the field as UNIQUE INDEX.

Now when trying to insert a duplicate index an error will be thrown and you can catch it like this:

```
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
```

Like this you can avoid the select query before every insert query. Just handle the error as you want.

Comment: why and what is wrong with the query infact ? I am quite curious why it works on my side ?

Comment: probably nothing is wrong. just suggesting a way to avoid an extra query to the database

Comment: what I am curious how come such a simple query could have failed?

Comment: the select query didn't fail. but if the registration number is not a unique key, is very easy to insert duplicates.

Comment: When you say very easy means in what scenario it might have failed?

Comment: As a general rule, yes it's very possible for the php logic to fail. If you can ensure your data integrity from the database, is the best method. You avoid redundant code in PHP, and also avoid many possible bugs.

Comment: What could fail it as its just a simple logic check right? Because I have this sort codes checking many other things too say my login page etc.